Student asking to see recommendation letter
A member of my lab is applying for STEM PhD positions in Europe. They asked me to write a letter of recommendation, and I am happy to write one. But they insist to see the contents of the letter first. They said if they don't agree with the letter they wouldn't want the letter to be sent. This troubles me, but I'm having difficulty explaining to them why this is a problematic behavior. How can I succinctly explain that this is not how recommendation letters work?

I am in agreement with Adam Přenosil's response, but want to add that you are under no obligation to write a letter at all.  I decline to write letters for students who do not waive their right to see the letters.  (I'm in the United States.)  And I note that you should decline to write a letter that would not be positive, also.

"How can I succinctly explain that this is not how recommendation letters work?" Note that in some countries (e.g. Denmark) this is exactly how recommendation letters work, and employers can only ask for letters through the applicant. It is a colossal PITA when recruiting internationally.

Be aware, if this person applies to the UK, they can get a copy of the letter via a Freedom of Informationen request and this right cannot be waived, even if the student wanted to.

You have to learn your legal situation. There are circumstances where you cannot refuse writing a recommendation letter and where the student can get access to the content of the letter.

@BobBrown What do you do with students applying to EU countries, where for most if not all mechanisms exist to see these letters ? Do you just refuse ? "I won't help you to apply outside the USA", while your prerogative, seems to be terribly unfair. If you take on EU students do you tell them at the start, that if they want to return to their home country they are on their own ? I really don't understand the US attitude. Most of Europe seems to be doing just fine under  "the student might (most of them don't check) be able to see my letter" policies, so it can't be critical.

@Marianne013 True, but by this point the recommendation letter would already have been sent.  The student does not have the legal right to see the letter in advance, as far as I know.

@Marianne013  It's simple.  You follow the law where you are.  More important, see the remark from cooperised.

@Marianne013 are you sure? How would Freedom of Information come into this if there isn't a public authority involved? I can see how it might be possible if the OP is working for a public university, but not under any other circumstances I can think of  (and, of course, IANAL, so I could be completely wrong).

@TimRias I would love to understand the logic behind this, as this de facto means letters of references are not confidential.  Can the referee be legally liable for writing a "poor" (or at least not strong enough) letter?

@ZeroTheHero I don't think so, unless what you wrote is actually slanderous. But I don't know the logic or reasoning behind this. I just have to deal with the consequences.

@cooperised There are definitely academic job applications in Europe which would require that the applicant upload the LOR themselves, therefore they would have access to the file before the application has been fully submitted.

Boy -- lot's of frame challenges in the answers.  The question was not "Are my feelings about confidential letters correct?"

@ZeroTheHero Yes, poor letters can be legally attacked in Germany, as far as I know. This causes letter writers to use "codes" to indicate certain issues with the candidate and if someone does not know these codes, they can inadvertently write a counterproductive letter for someone they intended to praise. Not sure about the laws in the US on that matter, though.

FYI. This is after I told them that I would have refused to write the letter if it were not going to be positive. Indeed the norm seems to be different in some countries.

@terdon It's not actually FOI that applies here, it's GDPR. The student can make a Subject Access Request to find out any or all information that the institution holds on them, which would include the letter of recommendation. (I think. IANAL either ;-))


How can I succinctly explain that this is not how recommendation letters work?

The recipient of the letter expects to read an honest account of the student's strengths and weaknesses from someone who has worked closely with them. This is where the value of the letter comes from. Showing letters of recommendation to students reduces this value, because then the recipient cannot know to what extent the letter is accurate and to what extent its contents were skewed by the (conscious or subconscious) pursuit of some other goal, such as flattering or not offending the student.

They said if they don't agree with the letter they wouldn't want the letter to be sent.

You could ask the student if there is something in particular that they are worried might appear in the letter. The student should not be trying to micromanage the contents of the letter, but I think it's fine for them to inquire whether you intend to mention such and such in the letter (say, an instance of very minor academic misconduct) and ask you not to submit the letter if you do.
On the other hand, I imagine this is more likely to be just an instance of general anxiety over the fact that two people are openly discussing the student's professional strengths and weaknesses and they have no control over what they are saying to each other. In that case I would try to convey the idea that (1) it's understandable that this is making them uncomfortable because this may be the first time they are faced with this experience, but (2) this is something that is normal in the professional world and something that they should try to come to grips with emotionally on their end.

Very good points about the student "coming to grips" with this aspect of reality... and being sympathetic to the (inescapable) stress...

I asked a few professors to recommend me around a year ago and they agreed, and I expected to never see what they wrote. To my surprise, one of them sent me a copy of their letter and said that it was "my right" to know what was in it. This was in the US. As I said, I was surprised but pleased.

In some countries, and I don't know about the US, a person will have a legal right to see a letter of recommendation you have written about them. Interestingly, the right usually only comes into existence after the letter has been received by the recipient; before then, whether the writer has communicated honestly with the recipient (or not) is only a hypothetical. But under various kinds of privacy legislation, the letter will constitute "personal information" thus creating the right of access. And the subject of the letter may have recourse to redress in circumstances.

But isn't this very similar to the situation where you grade a student? I mean, if you give a D to a student, he/she might also be offended, and you might be unconsciously biased to give a C because that particular student always complains about the grades. And assuming the general consensus that you should not write particularly negative recommendation letters, why do you want to treat them differently to other ways of evaluating the students knowledge and ability?

@JFabianMeier Yes, this is a similar phenomenon, though it is far pronounced in the case of LoR's, since a grade is just a letter/number based on largely objective data (the student answered X out of Y questions correctly -> they get a B), while a LoR is based on more on personal impressions. "Why do you want to treat them differently to other ways of evaluating the students knowledge and ability?" Because, as it says in the name, it's a letter. A personal communication from one person to a committee. It's not something that's a matter of public record, like the student's grades.

Also, to clarify my position, I am not endorsing either culture. I don't really care much myself. Both are ok as long as everyone is on the same page as to what the expectations are. I am just trying to state the (imo reasonable) justification for the practice as clearly as possible in the answer, since this is what the OP requested.

I want to point out that there is probably a different cultural expectation at play here. I know that in the US it is generally assumed and even enforced that people do not get to see the recommendation letters written about them. There are good abstract reasons for this convention but it is not universal.
You wrote that the candidate wants to apply to positions in Europe and the general attitude on this topic is a lot more relaxed. Recommendation letters may be secret from the subject of recommendation but there could also be an expectation that these letters are jointly written by the letter writer and the subject of recommendation. It depends on country and context.
You can of course still refuse to show them your letter but please be aware that this could be unusual for the specific position that your student is applying to. The university might assume that every candidate knows their recommendation letters and evaluate them accordingly.

While it might be appropriate for them to ask whether your letter would be positive, it isn't proper for them to demand to see the result. Some people are happy to share such letters with some applicants, but it isn't a requirement to do so.
To force sharing makes such letters largely meaningless and if the recipient knows that such sharing was required, would likely discount what was said in them.
It is to the candidate's benefit that the recipient has the sense that what is said is honest and not influenced by social or other pressures.
My response to such a demand would be to refuse to write the letter, telling the person to look elsewhere. In effect they want the power to write their own letters.

I liked Prenosil's response and this, but personally, this one would be my way to go. I do not like to be and would not recommend to let oneself being strongarmed, not even just because of anxiety. This threatens to just be the initial ignition of a fuse. Politely decline and exit left.

Not only is it proper, but IMNSHO the whole mechanism of evaluation-behind-person's-back is what's improper. "To force sharing makes such letters largely meaningless" <- No. " what is said is honest and not influenced by social or other pressures." <- The fact that the person being recommended does not know the contents does not guarantee honesty nor non-influence by pressure.

I second that. I'd probably refuse to write a letter for someone who makes such extreme demands.

@einpoklum the fact the the person being recommended does not know the contents does not guarantee honesty, no. However, the fact that the person recommended does know, pretty much guarantees dishonesty. Most of us will be affected if we know the letter's subject is going to read it. I'm sure most of us will still try to be as impartial as possible, but the tone and style is very likely to be slightly different if you know you are writing publicly. Perhaps only subconsciously, but some effect will be there.

@terdon: "but the tone and style is very likely to be slightly different if you know you are writing publicly. " <- As well it should be in a letter of recommendation, which is what the student is asking for.

@einpoklum There is a difference if the letter is visible by default (as I used to see often in some countries, because the person has to themselves add the letter to the submission) or if they insist to see it. In one case, the expectation is clear, in the other it is ambiguous. It is not neutral to the candidate's demand. This means that in countries with open references, there are positive-sounding codes for bad traits. Both, sender and receiver, agree on this as the referee has plausible deniability vis-a-vis the candidate. But in OP's case, this is not the default.

@einpoklum This means that, the referee in OP's case, has the option to make the context very clear to the recipient, could add one sentence at the beginning or the end of the letter, saying: "The candidate insisted on reading the reference letter before I would submit it." It is open, honest, public, as you propose, but you can imagine what message it sends even if (or especially!) the letter contains a glowing reference. In short, by keeping it open, you make the task harder for the referee to be honest while not being open for litigation and harder for the recipient to read.

@einpoklum the only reason to demand to see the reference before submission is if you distrust the referee. Then, why pick this referee at all? Outside of a true lack of options, this should really be the absolute exception. In short, open references (I have seen both kinds) create a big bunch of problems and do not provide much of an advantage. And yes, I would be happy for my candidates to see my references, as I never write references I do not believe helpful - but I still think they are far more effective when concealed.

@CaptainEmacs: That argument can be flipped: The only reason to hide the contents of the letter is if you want to sabotage their application by having them transmit a letter detrimental to the application. Doesn't sound very convincing, does it? Anyway, while concealed recommendations may perhaps be more effective - that would be effectiveness in convincing of their contents; and the student needs to know what that contents is, to decide whether to convey the letter or not.

@einpoklum Actually, the argument is not flipped. Frankly, if the letter is open, as often in Germany, people use codes unknown to inexperienced people. "communicates openly" -> "argues a lot" "not afraid to speak their mind" -> "offensive and insulting" "hardworking" -> "puts in a lot of effort without results". Guess what "sociable" or "friendly with colleagues" means, if you do not know the code. And legally safe.Additionally, requesting to approve a recommendation (because that's what it is when open recommendations are not the default) is an act of open distrust. Legitimate, but not nice.

@CaptainEmacs: "requesting to approve a recommendation is an act of open distrust" <- the recommender is expected to provide the letter to the person requesting the recommendation, so there is no request to approve a recommendation. The act of distrust is doing something other than giving the requester the letter.

@einpoklum Again, I am looking at the default. In Germany, the default used to be open letters. Then, of course, the requester can choose not to forward the reference, with the referee none the wiser. No problem. However, if in a culture where the letter is not usually passed through the requester, the latter demands to decide whether the referee can send it, personally, as referee, I would say if they do not trust me to write a good letter, they should not ask me in the first place. Without reason to suspect that the referee will write a bad letter, it is essentially...

@einpoklum ...a sign of distrust, in fact, disrespectful, and, frankly, while it has not happened to me, if it did, I would then suggest that they choose a referee they have more trust in rather than waste my time. A reference is a favour, not a duty, although I consider it a duty to write to people who I think deserve it. In many academic communities, much depends on goodwill.If the fact that there are bad players around means that one treats everyone as a potential bad player, one will lose a lot of goodwill, very quickly. If the community is known to be toxic, though, I am ready to concede.

"if in a culture where the letter is not usually passed through the requester, " <- That's a valid point. I wonder, though, if the student's cultural background is the same.


This troubles me

It shouldn't. If anything, it is behind-the-back evaluations that should trouble you.

I'm having difficulty explaining to them why this is a problematic behavior.

Of course you are, as the student's expectation of receiving the letter is not problematic. It is either a case of disagreeing norms, or, to judge more harshly - an unjust norm to which you subscribe. Yes, I know it's common in some parts of the world - but it's certainly not universal, and many regard it as inappropriate. As some commenters suggest, it is patently illegal in some places.

How can I succinctly explain that this is not how recommendation letters work?

You can present some of the points in other answers to this question; but - they're not very convincing, unless one tends to accept the basic legitimacy of these behind-the-back evaluations. So, you can explain the rationale, but I would claim you cannot convincingly explain it.

Now, some might object and ask "wait, how are we supposed to prevent the student from skewing the evaluation in their favor, without keeping the recommendation letter confidential?"
... and my answer is: You are not evaluating the student; they have asked you for a recommendation, not an evaluation. Whenever someone applies for some position, or grant, or prize, they try to make the best case in their favor. Even if letters were confidential - they would approach people who are very likely to write positive letters, and avoid people who are likely to write more negatively; and they would otherwise avoid disclosing parts of their record which are detrimental to their application. If you don't feel comfortable supporting the student making their best case - then don't write them a letter of recommendation.

Nicely put. Upvoted ... because I think you have managed to articulate something that I did not succeed in doing.

@CrimsonDark: It's even more troubling that the vast majority of 'answerers' on this thread cannot grasp this blatant instance of unfairness. The 'argument' that a letter of recommendation should be confidential to present a fair evaluation of the student is so ridiculous as to be laughable. You want to be fair? Then subject all students to the same exact test! Some students may give all sorts of benefits to their supervisor to write them a glowing (but not very honest) recommendation, and so the only thing that confidential letters achieve is to increase the rich-poor divide!

@user21820: It's not ridiculous and laughable, it's based on assumptions that we don't share. I can see understand the logic of it, I just don't accept it.

@einpoklum: I can understand why many people are irrational. It doesn't make it any more logical. But since you claim you can 'understand the logic of it', please explain what you think their assumptions about fairness are and how they yield the conclusion that we must keep recommendation letters confidential in order to uphold fairness. I am genuinely surprised and curious about such a claim. Thanks!

@user21820: They consider recommendation letters as a mechanism of consultation in an impartial(ish) evaluation process of candidates. So, instead of a recommendation, you are just facilitating the link between two senior academics. They will not speak frankly about you in your presence, or with you listening/resdig

@einpoklum: I presume you missed the last sentence of my initial comment. Please tell me how your point addresses that fact. Having recommendation letters that say all the bad things about the student seems to hurt the genuinely hardworking but non-conforming students more than any other group.

Don't make the mistake of conflating one issue (showing or not showing the letter to the student) with a separate issue (sending it, or not).
I would never think of writing a letter that I wasn't willing to show the student. Indeed, having been asked to write a letter of recommendation, I find myself more often being in the position of arranging a time to show the letter the student and discuss it with them, than being in the position of the student asking to see it!
However, my feeling is that when you are asked for a letter of recommendation, you should take the description at face value. If you can't recommend the person, then you can't write a letter of recommendation! Instead, tell the student that you can write a description of what you perceive to be their strengths and weaknesses but that you would find it difficult to recommend them.
If, after all this honesty, the student is willing to throw in their lot with your advice, then write your letter, show it to them, discuss it with them ... and send it!

In some ways, your two conflated separate issues are less separate than you make them out to be.  There should be no letter sent in if the requester and writer can't agree on the terms both can be comfortable enough with.


They said if they don't agree with the letter they wouldn't want the letter to be sent.

This shouldn’t actually be problematic if carried out in a transparent way that doesn’t compromise your integrity. You might answer the student:

Dear Student,
I can send you the letter to review and decide if you want me to send it. In that case, to ensure transparency I will include the following notice at the top of the letter: “At student [name]’s request, I shared the letter with them and they have reviewed it and approve of its contents.”
Please confirm you are still interesting in reviewing the letter and I
will send it to you.

You can perhaps add that a letter carrying such a notice may be discounted by the recipients; indeed, in the US and potentially other countries where there is a strong norm of not disclosing the content of letters of recommendation to the student, the letter may be dismissed as completely worthless. (By contrast, as others have commented, in certain European countries the practice of showing the letter to the student is viewed as less problematic or even pretty normal. To be clear, I have no way to tell what the effect of the notice would be in those locations, but it's potentially still worth cautioning the student about a possible effect.)

I think the fact that the student is asking for a veto on the letter makes it very problematic, although use of "approve" in your draft mitigates that somewhat..

@BobBrown It’s “problematic” in the sense that the student is deeply misguided about the feasibility of getting into grad school while insisting on such vetos. OTOH it “shouldn’t be problematic” in the sense that OP can accede to the student’s literal wish without compromising their ethics or integrity, by following my suggestion.

@BobBrown I do admit mu suggestion is a bit tongue in cheek and I’m not sure I would follow this advice myself, but perhaps saying something like this could be a way to get the student to understand the issue by addressing it indirectly instead of a more direct, finger-wagging sort of approach.

@BobBrown by the way, I wrote “approve of”, not “approve”. I would never imply that I allowed a student to approve the contents of my letter.

I missed that and apologize for my error.  However, in the current case the student is precisely requesting to approve the letter.  :-)

This is accurate within the US context and just assumes this is universal. It is not. You are free to disagree with conventions that assume recommendation letters are known to the student but belittling a student for that is not appropriate. And yes, I agree that the convention of secret letters is overall better but that does not imply that it is practiced that way everywhere.

@DanRomik I don't see the difference here. It seems the student is being given the chance to approve the contents of the letter (or not) by saying "yes, please send this letter" (or "no, please don't send it"). You're not allowing them to improve the contents, but that's different.

@EspeciallyLime The difference is that the student can either have an impactful letter with unknown content, or a worthless letter with positive content. Using Dan's method, the only outcome that helps the student and which the student wants, i.e. an impactful letter with positive content, can only be achieved by agreeing to a confidential LoR.

@Grumperson Sorry for not being clear. I understand (and agree with) the answer. What I was asking about is the distinction made in the comments between "approve the letter" and "approve of the letter". It seems to me that the student is doing both, in this scenario.

@EspeciallyLime I see what you mean. That's a fair point.

@quarague thanks, I agree with what you said and edited the answer to take your comments into account.

Adam Přenosil's answer covers the reasons.   It looks like you are in the United States.  FERPA (Federal Education Rights and Privacy Act) makes such letters "education records," which the student is entitled to see.  It is possible for a student to waive that right, and your institution's registrar can provide the necessary form.  In the absence of such a waiver, you should decline to write a recommendation.
If you receive a waiver and write a letter, I recommend closing the letter with the following:

The information contained in this letter is confidential and protected by United States Federal law. This information should not be disclosed to [name of student] or anyone in your organization who is not involved in the decision process regarding this individual. The information may not be disclosed to anyone outside of your organization without the consent of [name of student].

(I made this an answer rather than a comment because the FERPA implications are important in the United States.)

It is not clear to me who has any obligation to provide a copy of the letter to the student, nor that it is genuinely an educational record.  If, for example, the student requests a letter of recommendation from someone who is not affiliated with a public educational institution, the copy produced by the letter writer is not an educational record.  It might become an educational record when it is submitted as part of an application to some educational program, but then the receiving institution would be the party responsible for providing it to the student.

Additionally, if an instructor or other academic mentor is writing a letter for a student, my understanding is that there is almost nothing that the writer can say absent a FERPA waiver (e.g. you can't talk about how a student performed in your class without such a waiver).  So there definitely are FERPA implications, but I am not clear on where, exactly, they fall, and who is responsible for them.  If you can expand on this, it might be helpful.

@XanderHenderson  Well, I am not a lawyer, etc. and your own registrar is a better source.  That said, there is a specific exemption in FERPA that allows disclosure to a school to which the student has applied, so you don't need the waiver for an application to grad school.  You do need it for employment, security clearance, and other references.  And your letters are not confidential without that waiver.

@XanderHenderson  I see that I only answered your second comment.  OP has written "a member of my lab" which strongly implies that he or she is a faculty member.  FERPA applies to U.S. education institutions.  A letter written by a faculty member is an "education record" and so falls under FERPA.  The "waiver" I wrote about is a waiver of right to see the letter.  There's also a "release" that's sometimes called a waiver, that permits faculty to do things like give an employment reference.  They are different things.

I wouldn't recommend to go legal here but in this instance the US law you quote may be in direct contradiction to European data privacy laws. The letter clearly contains personal information about the student so the student may have a legal right to see it under GDPR rules. If OP is that worried about protecting the letter from the student they should just decline to write a letter at all.

@quarague  It looks like OP is in the United States.  If that's the case, he or she must follow U.S. law, which does not require that a student pre-approve a recommendation letter.  The issue here, and the crux of the question, is a student seeking pre-approval, effectively veto power.

If the student is an EU citizen (which I don't know but seems quite possible from context) and has the letter send to a university in the EU they can just claim GDPR rules. That the sender of the letter is outside of the EU would be totally irrelevant for that law. The argument is that OP is a EU citizen and the university has personal information about OP. But as I wrote, I wouldn't recommend to argue this on legal basis, it will just turn into a mess that doesn't help anyone.

@quarague it's not clear to me what the outcome of such a request would be, since the contents of the letter is personal information on two people. The university has to balance the GDPR subject access rights of one with the GDPR data protection rights of the other.

@quarague: I suspect all of that is moot, given that OP's student wants to see the letter before it is sent.

Depending on the country in which you, and the corresponding university, are in, you might not have a choice in whether the student gets to see the letter should you write one.
Many countries, such as the UK, have the concept of a Subject Access Request whereby a person can request a copy of any data/correspondence that an organisation holds on them. This would include any letters of recommendation that were sent. So they'd be able to get hold of it anyway.
Honestly, I don't see why you even feel as though you shouldn't let them see it. You shouldn't be writing anything in a letter of recommendation that you wouldn't say to a student's face. If you don't feel as though you can be honest about someone's weaknesses openly with them then maybe take a look at why you feel that way.
I also don't think it's unreasonable for a student to request a few letters of recommendation and then only submit the strongest. That's no different to guessing which professors are going to give you the best references and asking them to do it except it removes the guesswork and the chance of the student being torpedoed by a prof who's having a bad day.

"request a few letters of recommendation and then only submit the strongest" is objectionable because it wastes writers' time.

@BenVoigt - I don't mean like carpet bombing your whole dept, just if you need two, asking for three and discarding the worst

@ScottishTapWater to the person wasting time on the unsubmitted letter, how many are discarded doesn't really make a difference.  If a student expects honest communication with me, I expect honest communication from them.  I wouldn't write a letter if I was told this is the student's practice in advance, and would feel lied to if I wasn't told

@ScottSeidman - Alright then, I could agree with that if you were willing to discuss openly with them what the content of the letter would be

You touched the limits of "recommendations". In industry, this does not exist anymore (usually) because the recommendation is extremely subjective. Or it exists on an informal plane.
I was once asked to provide recommendation contacts for a position, I gave three of my friends who said that I was the incarnation of [you choose your deity], mixed with a genius-level professionalism. Since that company had old-fashioned ways of hiring, my friends also dropped that I of course have a weakness which is to be too hard-working (or something like that). Usefulness for the company: zero.
Academia believes in integrity and this is nice. The reality of the world is that you can be very good, but chemically incompatible with the person the jury expects a recommendation from. And that person can be an asshole.
This is to say that, as a European, I completely support your students. Either the letter chants their marvelousness, or it should be trashed. The receiving institution should have its own criteria and checks to decide about a candidate and not rely on sheer luck.

I would sit down with the student and explain/discuss what I would write in the letter completely honestly and in fairly specific terms, offer to answer any questions, and then just tell them that you only do confidential letters, if that is your personal pref.  The student can then decide if they still want your letter.  If they still want your letter, then write one, adhering as closely as you can to what you told the student you would write.

First of all, you do not need to explain anything to such a student. Since it is he/she who requests a favor from you, the game should be played on your terms or not played at all, period.
Second, the request for the letter would normally come directly from the hiring institution, and you are under no obligation to follow the student advice on whether to send the letter or not once you have written it.
So, what I would do is just to say something like "I'll be happy to write a letter for you, but then I'll send it regardless of what you think of it even if I show it to you. This is a take or leave offer, your choice. End of message." and then stick to these words no matter what.
Whether to show a letter to the student or not is entirely up to you. Sometimes I show some parts of the letters I write to the people I recommend to check that I haven't misstated some of their results or that my idea of what to emphasize in their work is not too far from theirs, but you are under no obligation to promote them unless you want to and under much less obligation to be led by them during that process in any way. It is customary to refuse to write anything for people you do not want to recommend for whatever reason rather than to write some killer stuff, but, again, the choice is yours. Once the request arrives, you are the sole authority as to what and how to write and you are solely accountable for your opinions. That should be communicated clearly to the students from the beginning and after that it should be their headache whether to add you to the list of potential reviewers or not. Don't overthink it!
Just my two cents, as usual :-)

If this conversation takes place before the student submitted their applications (with names of letter-writers included), then, if the student does not like what they see in your letter, the student most likely simply will not include your name in the application as one of the letter-writers. For what you describe to work, you would have to have such a conversation after receiving a request for a letter.

@MoisheKohan "if the student does not like what they see in your letter, the student most likely simply will not include your name in the application as one of the letter-writers" The conversation should occur before you write any letter whatsoever, and you shouldn't bother to write anything (or, at least, to inform the student that you did) before you get a request :-)

It doesn't seem right to send it in once the student sees it and asks that it not be sent in.   In fact, it seems downright mean.  It's much kinder to say "I only write confidential letters, so, with apologies for your inconvenience, I'm not able to write you a letter".  An even better way to go about it would be to state your condition of confidentiality when asked to write the letter, just to avoid putting the student in the situation of trying to dig up last minute recommendations later.

Another reason you can tell the student: the letter is likely to contain comparisons with other students. Even if these comparisons are indirect ("This student is in the top 10% of students I've ever supervised"), it's still improper for a student to read information that sheds light on other students' performance.

If it is improper for the student to have that information, it is also improper for the recipient of the letter, and vice-versa. Down with this cabal mentality.

@einpoklum The recipient has a valid reason to have the information--to help make admissions decisions. The applicant has no such valid reason.

The interest in making more informed admission decisions does not lend rights of access to students' information. I mean, I wan't to do research for curing cancer which would be helped by detailed information about people's daily habits. So can I get access to traffic and security cameras because of my "valid reason"?
